# How to display live tests progress bar, when use --logger:trx for Net Core TeamCity

Tags: .net-core, nunit, teamcity, nunit-3.0

Currently, when I logs result in trx file there are no *live tests progress bar* when I execute tests, Teare is displaying the only number of steps

[image]

**My configurations**

*Build Step :*
[image]

*Build Feature:*
**XML report type** : **TRX**

**My goal is :**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this answer

[teamcity-support.jetbrains.com](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000160640-How-to-display-live-tests-progress-bar-when-use-logger-trx-for-Net-Core?flash_digest=b615bf7fac275d1714fd6c98d75b49c3b6c91946)